# issue with samsung galaxy note 3 layout in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have developed an app which works on multiple devices.I have maded diffrent folders for **dimen** of devices such as

1. values-xhdpi
2. values-hdpi
3. values-xxhdpi etc.

Now it works like magic.But on samsung galaxy note 3 i have problem in layout.samsung galaxy note 3 hs **5.69 inch** screen & **386dpi** density.After searching i found galaxy note 3 lies in **'normal'** screen size & **'xxhdpi'** density.So i made new folder like

1. values-normal-xxhdpi

it worked but other devices which screen size is 4inch & above started picking this layout so how can i avoid the conflication?

please let me know?